# Were this Harry Potter character's initials supposed to spell a word?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

I am aware that In Universe the name was chosen for specifically stated reasons, but, *out of universe*, did J.K. Rowling intend for Albus Severus Potter to have initials which spell ASP — the name of a venomous snake?

Was this a coincidence or was it a not-so-private joke playing on Harry being a Parseltongue or Albus' fear of being sorted into Slytherin?

Or was it foreshadowing for *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*?

Comment: Sometimes a cigar is just a cigar.

Comment: As opposed to Cedric Rubeus Albus Potter?

Comment: @chirlu Occasionally a cigar is a Completely Independent Greatly Appreciated Reward.

Comment: I had considered that when compiling [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/144146/55866), but decided it was too far fetched.

Answer (score 2):

It is possibly just a coincidence but knowing how hints are made to future events and characters (for example the several references to Aberforth Dumbledore before we finally meet him in book seven/movie eight)it may be done on purpose. Also back in 2015 uk.businessinsider.com noticed this so it may be intended to be a reference to Albus's Hogwarts house.Unless in is confirmed by J.K herself we will never know.

Comment: This seems like idle guesswork. Do you have any evidence?

Comment: @Valorum Sorry if this is a bad answer as I'm new and just trying to get used to answering questions.Hopefully in the future I will be able to back up this answer with some evidence

Comment: If you have a look at someone like @Bellatrix or Slytherincess , you'll see that their Harry Potter answers are *always* upvoted because they insist on backing up everything with quotes, book references, interviews and evidence.

Comment: @Valorum I've changed my answer to hopefully make it better but if there are still other things I can do to make it better then please tell me so I can hopefully make this answer better. I am still working on how to put blockquotes in so when I work out how to put those in  my answers will be MUCH better. In about 2-3 weeks I will be much better. This is only my second answer ever so I will be a lot better in the future.

Comment: You can add quotes using the quick links above the answer panel or by pasting in the quote and putting > in front of it.

Comment: @Valorum thanks for helping if you go onto my profile and go onto my other answer you will see there's a lot more evidence.The reason there's no quotes on this answer is I couldn't find any. Hopefully this has cleared up this mess.

Comment: As much as I hate to say it, sometimes there's just no answer available. When that happens, rather than posting  a poor answer I tend to either a) Contact the author and ask them for their thoughts or b) admit defeat. What I don't usually do is go for option c) posting an answer with nothing to back it up

Comment: I will end this now there is no answer so far. In the future their may be an answer but here in June 2018 there is no answer.

Comment: @Valorum - Guesswork perhaps, but surely it's Not Nice to call it "idle."

Comment: @Valorum I agree with Adamant; even if guesswork it's still not idle. And it's interesting that it's been noticed publicly too. I admit that it's arguably not worth an answer but it still shows some effort and that's to be commended, surely? I feel that way anyway. As for the OP keep it up; you'll find things you can answer in time if you keep at it. Anyway have another +1 to help you with rep.