# Why did Albus Severus Potter get sorted into Gryffindor in the first alternate timeline?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

In *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child* play, Albus was [originally sorted into Slytherin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/139431/931), but after

> Albus and Scorpius disarmed Cedric in past and returned to a new timeline (in which Ron and Hermione never fall in love), they found that Albus was in Gryffindor.

How did Hermione's choice of not dating Victor Krum influence the events such that Albus' personality traits became that of Gryffindor? Maybe, it has to do with Albus not getting Hermione as his Aunt and/or not getting Rose as his cousin and/or getting Padma as his Aunt and/or getting Panju as his cousin. But, how exactly did it change him?

Comment: For the *exact* answer you are probably going to have to ask the writers.

Comment: probably more just about the 'butterfly effect' than any real logic. One could assume though that his original sorting into Slytherin was due in part to his befriending of Scorpius on the train. In the first alternate timeline, due to <insert random time things here> - they may not have met and / or Albus asked the hat to be in Gryffindor (like his father)

Comment: Seems dupey of [Why was Albus Severus sorted into Slytherin?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/139434/20774) since it addresses things that didn't/couldn't happen in the alternate timeline.

Answer (score 3):

Albus convinces the Sorting Hat to put him in Gryffindor in this reality - as his father did in the original one. This is what is sort of hinted at in the original "19 Years Later..." but of course the play includes meeting Scorpius and looking at things differently. In the first alternate timeline full of smaller changes, this is one of them.

> Albus: But how did I get sorted into Gryffindor?
>
> Ron: You persuaded the Sorting Hat, don't you remember? Panju bet you that you couldn't get into Gryffindor if your life depended on it, so you chose Gryffindor to spite him.

Comment: Pretty sure that the original epilogue was implying a Slytherin sorting, seeing as Rowling continued doing that in her other writings about Albus.

Comment: @Ibid - do you mean just this play?

Comment: No (that's not even her writing). I'm referring to the 2014 Daily Prophets.

Comment: @ibid - What does it say about him there? I've read them and don't recall this.

Comment: There's [a part contrasting Albus to the rest of his family using the colors green and red](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/144146/55866). It's probably open for interpretation, but it seemed to me to have been deliberate foreshadowing.

Comment: @ibid - Very interesting! But I'm not sure that the 2014 writing means there was this intention in the 2007 book. He is just as worried about it as Harry was! Anyway - it is stated that he ended up in Gryffindor because he convinced the Sorting Hat, which he hadn't done in the original timeline.